# Conflito entre última cell da ListView e FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile, listview

Na última cell da minha **`ListView`** ocorre um conflito pois o
**`FloatingActionButton`** da tela fica tapando dois botões como mostra na imagem:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Queria poder aumentar a área de scroll da minha **`ListView`** ou poder incluir algo no fim do scroll que fizesse com que os botões não criem conflitos de espaço.

---

Tentei incluir uma cell a mais no **`ListAdapter`** e deixar ela toda em branco, isso funciona mas quando chego no fim da fila e visualizo, se eu der um scroll para cima, outras cell também ficarÃo brancas, como mostra na imagem:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Estou usando na classe java um `extends FragmentList`

Comment: Tenta colocar algo como rodapé (um layout, um baner), acredito que seu problema seja uma questão de design

Comment: O ListView está em um LinearLayout vertical. Se eu colocar outro layout ocupando um espaço dentro deste LinearLayout, ele fica fixo na tela e a lista em cima dele. Gostaria que a Lista aproveitasse ao máximo da área da tela. Acrescentando esta área apenas ao final do scroll da lista.

Comment: Não vejo nesse layout o FloatingActionButton.

Comment: O FloaringAcrionButton está na MainActivity, nela eu chamo um Fragmento, que é a lista. O FloatingActionButton fica na frente consequentemente quando dou um scroll até o fim da lista ele fica na frente dos botões azuis como mostra na primeira imagem.

Comment: Se reparar isso acontece em grandes apps e não tem muito importância. Se olhar o whatsapp você vai reparar que a contagem de mensagens não lidas aparecem atrás do novo FloatingActionButton.